# What level can I choose my advanced class?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In Star Wars the old republic, you choose a class at character creation and later you get to choose an advanced class (such as gunslinger for smuggler).  What level does that happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make the decision when you leave the starting planet. You also need to be at level 10, you may not be level 10 at when you reach this point so you'll need to go back if you leave that area.

To leave the starting planet/area you need to complete all the story quests.

Comment: In my experience, if you complete all soloable side-quests, you will be at least level 11 when you've completed the starting planet. If you rush the main story quest and skip everything else, you could leave the planet at about level 7.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have hit 10 you will be allowed to move to fleet then go to either Corusant or Dromund Kas. When you arrive on fleet you can choose your advanced class at your class trainer. Then they will tell you who to go to. Hope that helps guys.